# How to create a subsection in django admin site of a model with some special filters?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have a Law model and a custom command that amend Laws every 20 days. Now I want to email the admin that Laws are amended with a link redirecting to the admin site.

In the admin section, I need a subsection of laws named `LatestAmendedLaws` that filters all the recently amended laws, so the admin can verify if laws are correctly amended.

Here is the admin.py of Laws:

```
@admin.register(Law)
class LawAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'rs_number',
        'created'
    )
```

usually when a law is amended the created date updates. so we can filter with the created date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create additional Admin page on proxy model of Law.

models.py:

```
class LatestAmendedLaws(Law):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = "Latest Amended Laws"
```

then in admins.py:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

@admin.register(LatestAmendedLaws)
class LatestAmendedLawsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'rs_number',
        'created'
    )

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).filter(created__gte=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=20))
```

Comment: Thanks, Preator. This actually adds a new subsection to the admin dashboard. still, I need to modify the query to get amended laws. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: check the get_queryset override I suggested